# Какое должно быть окончание у местоимения "который"?

Tags: окончания, местоимения

> Олег один из красивейших людей, с **которыми** я когда-либо встречалась.

Подруга утверждает, что здесь должно быть "которым", я же склоняюсь к "которыми", так как считают, что местоимение выступает в роли дополнения к слову "людей".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верной дорогой идёте, товарищ! И потом, не забыли ли Вы народную мудрость: "Выслушай подругу и поступи наоборот"? О_о

"Которыми" принадлежат "людям", с которыми героиня эпизода встречалась. Олег может отдыхать.

Людям - каким? Вот таким, с которыми.

Comment: Запомню народную мудрость)) Спасибо за ответ :)